# How to run process of internet connected computer?

Tags: c#

is it possible to run process of internet connected (not connected locally) computer using psexec or WMI or any other way? i have IP address username and password of remote computer. psexec or WMI works fine in local network.

Answer (score 0):

To use such functions as Windows Management Instrumentation or the PSEXEC service you must be trying to connect to a remote machine that is running on the same Domain/Network.

Comment: thanks for reply Derek. but is there any way for different Network? thanks in advance.

Comment: No, I wouldn't think so, your pretty much opening yourself up for computer hacking that way.

Comment: i have IP address username and password of remote computer. so how can it be hacking?

Comment: I'm not saying that you are hacking, I'm saying that the reason behind  such tools working within private networks rather than from private network to private network is to prevent hacking. It opens itself up to trouble.